# Ansible play to upload ftp file using lftp

Tags: ansible, ftp, eof, lftp

I setup ftp server using ansible and verified it's working by manually doing lftp from my localhost

I uploaded a file using put and was able to find the file in ftp server, when i do ls.

I wrote a play to upload file to ftp server and it returned success always. However, i can't find the file that I uploaded using my play. Then i edited my play to display result register and found a warning. See below

```
---
- name: test ftp upload
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: install lftp
      yum:
        name: lftp
    - name: upload file
      shell: >
        lftp ansible1.example.com<<EOF
        cd pub
        put /etc/hosts
        bye
        EOF
      register: result

    - name: display result
      debug:
        var: result
```

Below is the output I got after running the play

```
PLAY [test ftp upload] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [install lftp] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [upload file] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [display result] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "lftp ansible1.example.com<<EOF cd pub put /etc/hosts bye EOF\n",
        "delta": "0:00:00.010150",
        "end": "2020-04-04 09:15:26.305530",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-04-04 09:15:26.295380",
        "stderr": "/bin/sh: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "/bin/sh: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')"
        ],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am not able to understand the warning w.r.t EOF part and if it's the reason for the file upload not happening. Because, I use the below shell script (which is basically the same steps from the play) to upload file and it works perfect.

```
lftp ansible1.example.com<<EOF
cd pub
put /etc/hosts
bye
EOF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the wrong scalar block style indicator (see [documentation](https://yaml-multiline.info/)) for your shell command.

You need to keep the new lines in your piece of shell code. In this case, you have to use the literal scalar block indicator: `|`

You have used the folded scalar block indicator (`>`) which will basically convert new lines to spaces (although it is a little more complicated as explained in [this other source](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)). So your current piece of shell code expands to a single line in your shell (you can debug the value to see for yourself):

```
lftp ansible1.example.com<<EOF cd pub put /etc/hosts bye EOF
```

The following should fix your current problem:

```
    - name: upload file
      shell: |
        lftp ansible1.example.com<<EOF
        cd pub
        put /etc/hosts
        bye
        EOF
      register: result
```